# Implementing OAUTH provider Java - Generating Consumer Key and Secret

Tags: java, oauth

My application is an oauth provider. It works fine when I use pre-generated Consumer Key and Secret. I wanted to know what would be the best way to generate Consumer Key and Secret in java. Are there any libraries that I could use to do this. basically I want to create an app registration page where in other applications can register. I am planning to ask details like call back URL and application name. I just want to generate random Consumer Key and secret based on those details. I am planning to use HMACSHA1. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: I don't know if this is an answer... take your favorite book, flip to a random page, pick a paragraph of about 6-8 sentences, and hash that block of text. The resulting hash should be a sufficient salt that you can add the other details to in order to generate the keys from. Or I may be completely off my rocker :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate a 20-40 character long string of cryptography-secure random characters. In order to do this, you need to use a CSRNG. A java implementation is shown below.

```
public final class KeyGenerator
{
  private static final String symbols = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGJKLMNPRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_"; 
  private final Random secureRandomProvider = new SecureRandom();
  private final char[] buffer;

  public KeyGenerator(int length)
  {
    if (length < 1)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("length < 1: " + length);
    buffer = new char[length];
  }

  public String CreateKey()
  {
    for (int idx = 0; idx < buffer.length; ++idx) 
      buffer[idx] = symbols.charAt(secureRandomProvider.nextInt(symbols.length()));
    return new String(buffer);
  }
}
```

Comment: It must be truly random. Since they are basically the keys to the front door, you need to make sure that someone with a key cannot guess what another key will be.

Comment: Thanks all for your prompt responses. I ended up using "javax.crypto" package to generate "HmacSHA1" keys based on input srtings entered while app registration.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your prompt responses. I ended up using "javax.crypto" package to generate "HmacSHA1" keys based on input srtings entered while app registration.

Comment: fancy sharing some code as i would like to do exactly the same thing!